# Why does ZSH hang on empty redirection?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

To truncate a file in a unixy environment you would commonly use:

```
$ > file
```

In bash (also dash), the file is truncated (or created if it doesn't exist), and then the prompt returns. In zsh, the file is truncated/created, but it hangs. You have to `Ctrl-C` to be able to use the prompt again.

Redirecting non-empty output works without a problem:

```
zsh$ cat nonempty.file > file
zsh$
```

#### The question is:

Is this behaviour expected or not? Is zsh **wrong**?

Comment: You can press `ctrl-d` instead of `ctrl-c` to eof the input.

Comment: Yep, or ctrl-\ to sigquit ;-) but that's not the issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not really a zsh user but seems like `> file` in zsh is the same as `cat > file` in bash. To create a new file or truncate it in zsh, use `: > file`. This also works for bash.

---

#### UPDATE:

Found this in zsh manual:

> - **REDIRECTIONS WITH NO COMMAND:**
>
>   When  a  simple  command consists of **one or more redirection operators** and zero or more parameter assignments, **but no command name,** `zsh` can behave in several ways.
>
>   If the parameter **`NULLCMD`** is not set or the option `CSH_NULLCMD` is set, an error is caused.  This is the  `csh`  behavior
>   and `CSH_NULLCMD` is set by default when emulating `csh`.
>
>   If  the  option **`SH_NULLCMD`** is set, the builtin **`:`** is inserted as a command with the given redirections.  This is the
>   default when emulating **`sh`** or **`ksh`**.
>
>   Otherwise, **if the parameter `NULLCMD` is set, its value will be used as a command with the given redirections.**  If both
>   `NULLCMD` and `READNULLCMD` are set, then the value of the latter will be used instead of that of the former when the
>   redirection is an input.  **The default for `NULLCMD` is `cat`** and for `READNULLCMD` is `more`.

On my system, the default is:

```
$ echo $ZSH_VERSION
4.3.10
$ echo $NULLCMD
cat
$ echo $READNULLCMD
/usr/bin/pager
$
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `: > file` works well in zsh, and doesn't hang. But `cat > file` does. Despite hanging, the files are actually created/truncated. So it's not a question of what works, it's a question of **why** it's happening in the first place.

Comment: `cat > file` is not hang, it's waiting for input.

Comment: If you want the reference doc, see https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Redirections-with-no-command